# How to set the y limit using plt.rcParams to zero. (Charting a Pandas df and saving image to disk)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My DataFrame is a time series.
I'm using...

```
df.plot()
```

and it basically zooms in on the y axis but I would like the plot to show y values from 0 to my df's max value

I tried...

```
plt.ylim(0)
```

But it just plots a blank graph in addition to the graph I don't want.

I also tried...

```
.set_ylim(bottom=0)
```

on the end, and it plots but I can't get python to store this. It turns the plot into x, y coordinates somehow.

[image: My current output]

Just to be redundant about it... This y axis stops at 4. I would like it to go to 0 and have the who chart be not zoomed in like that so other graphs can be more easily compared to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ylim()` usually takes [2 arguments `(bottom, top)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html?highlight=ylim#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim). However, if you only want to change one of the limits, you have to specify which using `top=` or `bottom=`

You could simply do:

```
df.plot(...)
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
```

Comment: WORKS. When I applied your answer I put it AFTER the df.plot() line. As stated in the OP, I was getting two graphs trying to use it because I put .ylim before it. In other words, if you vice versa your answer's lines, that's what I had. I wonder if such a dumb questions should stay up.

Comment: `plt.ylim(bottom=0)` is the same as `plt.ylim(bottom=0, top=None)`, which is the same as `plt.ylim(0, None)` and that is the same as `plt.ylim(0)`. So the key is not to use kwargs, but rather not to put `plt.ylim` in front to pandas figure creation.